# ASP Textbox keeps data, input element cleared

Tags: asp.net, html-input

I have an aspx.net page with two asp textboxes and two input elements.

```
<asp:TextBox class="input1" ID="TextBoxAirportPkup" placeholder="Enter Flight Number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>...
<asp:TextBox class="input1 " ID="TextBoxAirportName" placeholder="Airport" runat="server" />...
<input id="airPickupdateInput" class="timepicker datepicker" placeholder="Pickup Date" type="text" />
<input type="text" id="airPickuptimeInput" class="timepicker" placeholder="Pickup Time" />
```

When I click on an unrelated button and run some code-behind, the text in the TextBox elements is preserved, but the text in the input elements is cleared. Page_Load is called with IsPostback == true, but I run no code in that case. Why is this happening, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

Add runat="server" and the server side can see the input elements.

Comment: ASP.NET View State Overview https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The two Textbox retain their state due to the fact they are server controls, and therefore they have access to the pages view state which is designed to persist state across postbacks.

The two input controls are html controls, they do not have access to view state and therefore are not repopulated after a postback (which is in effect like refreshing the page).

In order to preserve the state of these inputs after the postback you either need to make them server controls or alternatively use a hiddenfield control and use javascript to write the value from the hidden control back into the inputs if they cannot be server controls for whatever reason.

It is also possible to use Ajax to submit the other actions or forms without causing a postback of the whole page and therefore nigate the need to refresh all of the data on the page.  This will require some restructuring of your application.

for more information on view state please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic3